# How to change background color of a custom button designed in XAML at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have made a custom Button using expression blend and pasted it in my xaml code .

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle RadiusY="21" RadiusX="20" Stroke="White"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
 </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I have then used this resource in my c# code to change color, font size, background , foreground and all properties dynamically possible.

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createButton();
    }
    public void createButton()
    {            
        Button buttton = new Button { Height = 100, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Width = 300,  Content = " Button", Style = this.Resources["ButtonStyle1"] as Style };                  
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(buttton);

    }
```

But i am unable to do so , no change is being reflected in button. 
Is there any way . 
I know that i have to change color of rectangle . But do not know how to do it . 
I tried a lot. 
 Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but is there any property like UseVisualStyleBackground ? or see this link if it can help http://diggthedrazen.com/2011/06/30/creating-elements-dynamically-in-windows-phone/

Comment: sorry Jax, but still i didn't got any clue.

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907977/on-item-selection-changing-the-color-of-a-rectangle-which-is-part-of-a-listboxi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what properties should affect *which*? You created a custom control template for your button which means you decide how it is drawn. If you take a look at your template, your button consists of a `Grid` with two child controls: a `Rectangle` and a `ContentPresenter`.

Now, when you say:

```
var btn = new Button
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Blue);
};
```

What should become blue? The `Grid`? The `Rectangle` control? `ContentPresenter`? This question is not answerable in principle and you need to decide which control in the `ControlTemplate` inherits parent's properties.

To put it in another words: `Button`'s properties are transferred down to the controls in the `ControlTemplate` via `TemplateBinding`. So if you wanted to transfer the meaning of `Button.Background` to `Rectangle.Background`, you would change the template to this:

```
<Rectangle RadiusY="21" RadiusX="20" Stroke="White"
            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
```

And now you get something that might be what you wanted. When you set `Button.Background` you merely transfer it to the target subcontrol since there is no `Button` in the visual tree, it is replaced by it's control template.

Comment: Thanks Toni ,sorry if i didn't explained it properly,   Actually i wanted to change Background of rectangle.